# Set X11 screen resolution with xrandr

Tags: linux, xorg, resolution

It's been a while since I've needed to use xrandr. I remember being able to just use -s# to specify which configuration you wanted to apply for example if I had:

```
CRT1 connected 1400x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200      60.0 +
   1400x1050      60.0* 
   1280x1024      60.0     47.0     43.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       60.0  
   1152x864       60.0     47.0     43.0  
   1280x768       59.9     56.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1024x768       60.0     43.5  
   800x600        60.3     56.2     47.0  
   720x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

And I wanted to set the screen resolution to 1024x768_60.00 I would specify `xrandr -s9` and the 9th configuration would be applied. However, this does not seem to work anymore. How do I apply one of the printed resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
xrandr -s 1024x768
```

Tested with:

```
$ xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.4.0
Server reports RandR version 1.4
```